# How to properly track conversion on an Android app funnel?

Tags: android, google-analytics, facebook-sdk-4.0

We have an Android app that requires users to fill out a form in multiple steps on various pages. For marketing purposes, we need to know what the conversion is at each step of the funnel and how the conversion differs based on the user acquisition source (for example what is the conversion for a user coming from Facebook Ads compared to a user coming from Google Ads). At the moment, we have the Facebook SDK for Android as well as the Google Analytics Services SDK for Android installed.

Here is what we need to have **for each acquisition channel**:

- **Step 1:** # of users who achieved it, conversion rate, monetary value associated with the completion of the step
- **Step 2:** # of users who achieved it, conversion rate, monetary value associated with the completion of the step
- ...

We already have events set up on the app but the issue is that they can be triggered multiple times per user, thus making any analysis impossible.

**Some ideas:**

- Is there any way to change the way events are triggered that would make the analysis easier?
- Is it possible to solve this directly in Google Analytics by making sure that we take into consideration only the first time the event is triggered by a user?
- Would the installation of Google Tag Manager be of any help?

Any idea on how we could do it properly would be greatly appreciated.